# Bringing order by using ORDERY BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Suppose i have a customer table which has `CusID`, `name`, `country`, `phone`, 
  `email`.

Example: i want to get `CusID`, `name`, `country` of all customer in every country from the table, but i want to build a list by bringing up the customers living in `USA` and `Canada` first , and finally ordered them by `CusID`

I want a list like this

```html
<table  style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <td>CusID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Country</td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>Mac</td>
  <td>USA</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>04</td>
  <td>Bue</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>08</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>Kev</td>
  <td>USA</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>Frank</td>
  <td>France</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>03</td>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Japan</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>Zimmer</td>
  <td>UK</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>06</td>
  <td>Sok</td>
  <td>Brazil</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>07</td>
  <td>Mad</td>
  <td>Iran</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>09</td>
  <td>Ome</td>
  <td>China</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>Uno</td>
  <td>Italy</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried, what is the actual vs. the expected outcome? Give sample data and query. Please [edit] your question. This is not a "please do my work for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple conditions in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when country = 'USA' then 1
               when country = 'Canada' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         CusId
```